# What's wrong with this WordPress MySQL DB Query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, query-performance

I have a pretty busy wordpress site. >3M pageviews per month. The last couple of weeks we're having MySQL issues. CPU over 500% (8 core, 256GB RAM, dedicated hardware) and very slow performance.

So I found this query dozens of times.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
 WHERE 1=1
 AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'tie_views')
 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
 AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
 ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0
 DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

It looks like it's waiting to time out and then get killed. Can someone explain what this is ding exactly? And can anyone can tell me what's wrong with this query?

Please advice...

Comment: It depends on the amount of data...? But maybe another query is slowing this one down.

Comment: The wp_posts table has 170k records.
The wp_postmeta table has 1.8M records

Comment: Indexes on (post_id,meta_key) and (post_type,post_status) might be useful. And although it won't do anything for performance, replace your GROUP BY clause with a DISTINCT modifier.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query) and we can probably identify missing indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with this query. I modified it to work with a database I have and I'm able to grab `10,000` records in `0.0409` seconds (on a db with 21k `posts` records and 137k `postmeta` records). That said, I have also modified my database a little bit, including partial indexes on the `postmeta` table which does speed up queries like these.

One thing you'll notice across WordPress is that larger and larger sites get slower and slower, especially when using a `meta_query`. (Generally it's worse and more noticeable when you're using multiple `JOIN`s on the same table with `OR […] WHERE`).

There are a million Articles/SO Questions/Docs on "speed up a slow meta query in WordPress", and unfortunately you'll kind of be on your own to find which one works for you.

If that query is being run dozens of times (per page load??) make sure you're caching the results. Make sure you've got some good [Object Caching](https://wp-rocket.me/blog/object-caching-use-wordpress/) going, and consider page caching as well - if you haven't already.

You could also consider caching the results of that query with [WordPress Transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) - which basically set the query results to a temporary option in the `wp_options` table, for a length of time you determine (30 seconds, 4 hours, 6 weeks, whatever) - and it will pull from there instead of running the query every time, until it expires.

One last thing that may or may not be related, is make sure your `wp_options` table isn't bloated. Lots of plugins leave lots of bloated information in there to die. And the default storage options set them the `autoload: true` which means they get loaded into memory on *every page load*. I've seen "lightweight/small/etc" websites that had a bloated `wp_options` table with hundreds of megabytes of years old garbage in it causing extreme load times, timeouts, and crashing.

So basically

- Look at ways to speed up meta queries, as they're inherently slow
- Turn on Object Caching and/or use WP Transients
- Consider Page caching
- Flush out useless junk from your options table

Comment: I disagree. In the absence of any aggregating functions, inclusion of a GROUP BY clause is inherently wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I worded that poorly - I meant that the query itself shouldn't be causing any enormous load spikes and timeouts, even if it's not the most performant query ever (*at that rate, which native WordPress [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) is?*) Removing the outer GROUP (or using SELECT DISTINCT) is a part of a few of the "Speed up meta query" results - I'm just not sure that alone will fix OPs problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The basic design of WP is "EAV" (Entity-Attribute-Value).  This is a grossly inefficient way to store an active data point such as view-counter or "Like"-counter.  And, as you are finding, it does not scale well.

Such counters should be in a *dedicated* column with a *numeric* datatype.  I don't know if there is a way within WP to add such a column.  Assuming it is not possible, the following will help *some* by improving the indexing of `postmeta`: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta